# Type ahead search in the react js tables

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a table which is like

```
<UserTabel dataList={this.props.dataList} />
```

And

```
<div className="table-responsive">
        <table className="table table-hover" id="job-table">
          <thead>
            <tr className="text-center">
              <th scope="col" className="wc-30">Sr.No.</th>
              <th scope="col">Company Name</th>
              <th scope="col">Technology</th>
              <th scope="col">Title</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody className="text-center">
            {this.props.data && this.props.dataList.content && this.props.dataList.content.length > 0 && this.props.dataList.content.sort((a, b) => b.createdAt - a.createdAt).map((item, key) => {
              return (
                <tr key={key}>
                  <td className="font-weight-bold wc-30">{key + 1}</td>
                  <td>{item.technology}</td>
                  <td className="font-weight-bold">17</td>
                  <td title={item.title} className="jd-name-container justify-content-center align-items-center">
                    <div className="jdName">{item.jdName}</div>
                    {(key + 1 === 1) && <div className="badge new-badge badge-warning-custom">New</div>}
                  </td>
                  <td className="font-weight-bold">30</td>
                  <td className="font-weight-bold">30</td>
                </tr>
              )
            })}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    )
```

Now the data which I have is like in this format .

```
this.props.datalist = {
    "content": [{
        "id": "5b7d4a566c5fd00507501051",
        "companyId": null,
        "title": "Senior/ Lead UI Developer",
        "jobDescription": null,
        "technology": "java"
    },{
        "id": "5b7d4a566c5fd005075011",
        "companyId": null,
        "title": "ead UI Developer",
        "jobDescription": null,
        "technology": "angular"
    }]
}
```

Now, In this Now,I have one input box ,

```
 <input type="text"
                id="searchJob"
                className="form-control-sm border-0 flex-grow-1"
                placeholder="Company Name / Technology / Job title" />
              <i className="fa fa-search search-job"></i>
            </div>
```

Now, Here what I trying is as soon as user types in this `onChange`, I need to search in the `dataList` in two criterias which are `Title and Technology` , then I need to show user only that row to the user.

So, is there any way through which I can do this ?

Thanks in advance. Any thing will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is create a function like getDataList() which filters the data for a given criteria. The criteria can then use your enteredText. Finally, use the created function to populate the data for your table.

```js
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {enteredText: null};
}

function onChange(newText) {
  this.setState({enteredText: newText});
} 

function getDataList() {
  return this.props.datalist.content.filter(c => (c.title === this.state.enteredText || c.technology === this.state.enteredText));
}
```